# View image in WebView that has no file extension

Tags: android, image, webview

In my Android app, I am using the following code to view an image:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///mnt/sdcard/Temp/somefile");
```

The webview however will not display the image if the filename does not have an extension. Is there some way to indicate to webview that this is a jpg?

I also tried loadData and loadDataWithBaseURL with html including an img tag but that didn't help either.

Comment: All files in my app are stored without extensions for security purposes. Modern day browsers can automatically detect content type or at the minimum can be given a hint through the mime type.

Comment: Have you tried doing a base64 encoding of the image and using that in the img tag for the loadData? Not exactly the right way to do it, but worth a try.

Comment: You can only do that with small images. My images are fairly large.